# Apache returns Content-Type text/plain instead of text/html

Tags: apache, content-type

I’m migrating an application from HP-UX to Solaris

Apache 1.3.27
HP-UX B.11.11 U 9000/800 
Solaris SunOS 5.10 Generic_147440-10 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise

In solaris, my whole application is working fine except for one single page that is not being interpreted.
My webserver it’s sending back a wrong Content Type to my web page. Instead of sending text/html, it’s sending text/plain. I've already checked this with Fiddler.
When I visit the resource I only see the html code, as a plain text.
The CGI scripts are okay.
I’ve already changed the DefaultType to text/html in the httpd.conf file.
Also the mime.types file has the content-type .html and .htm extensions
Is some other parameter that I could set in the httpd.conf file to send the correct content type?

PS. I can't upgrade apache because  I'm not authorized to do that. I must work with this environment.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Jorge, you have probably found the solution, since it is a year old post. I will post it anyways, because for now "duckduckgo-ing" does not yield the answer (or I am a bad duckduckgoer). It is my small (and first) contribution to the amazing knowledge base, which I use frequently.

**Solution:**

Module `mime` should be added and configured.

I found that if the module is loaded (either built-in into Apache or as mod_mime.so) but the file `mime.types` does not exist (or sits somewhere else, not where I "said" it is in my TypesConfig) then Apache does not start producing an error message. If the module is not loaded (or not compiled in) then I have the *text/plain instead of text/html* exactly as the topic-starter described.

Check whether the module is compiled in into Apache executable (to check that type

`#httpd -l`

or

`#apache2 -l`

depends on how it is called on your system). If it is not compiled in, then you need to add it manually in the httpd.conf (or apache2.conf, again depends on your system)

```
LoadModule mime_module {full path to your mod_mime.so without the braces}
```

You can find where it sits exactly with command [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

```
#find / -name mod_mime.so
```

Then, somewhere below in httpd.conf add the following lines

```
# mime
TypesConfig conf/mime.types
DefaultType text/plain
```

and restart your Apache. Please notice that path to file `mime.types` in `TypesConfig` is not a full path to the file but rather related to your `ServerRoot` path, so adjust accordingly (if needed).

**Caution!**

To check whether it worked or not first of all clear your browser cache! It took me a while to find out that the server already fixed but both my browsers provide an old copy of the page, EVEN THOUGH I did push "reload page" button. Only worked after I cleared the cache explicitly.

**PS**

I think it should have been on *serverfault*, should not it be?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that Apache returned Content-Type text/plain instead of text/html.

What I did to solve the problem is:

Step 1: Find where file mime.types is. In my Ubuntu box, it is
    /etc/mime.types, which should include the following line:

```
text/html        html htm shtml
```

Step 2: In apache2.conf, replace "TypesConfig conf/mime.types" with "TypesConfig /etc/mime.types".

Step 3: Restart apache and it works.

My Apache version is:

```
$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
```